# Social links opening in same window

Tags: html, wordpress

I'm setting up my own new website, i'm using free Portra theme.
std it's a widget free template. I managed to add a widget, but now my social links are always opening in the same window.
I would like them to open in a new tab or window.
I tried with `<A target="_blank" href......></a>` but no luck

The only thing that worked half is oncklick that opened my link in a new window, but in the background that also opened the same window in the site.

I cannot figure this one out. Please help
I think it's overruled somewhere by a preloader, but to be honnest my knowledge doens't reach that far. And google did not give any solution

The site link is http://www.sergioprodi.com/wordpress (so I hope this will do to get the code)

The site is not published yet so don't look at content please, t's not defintive ;-)

Thanks in advance

---

I tried all these, no luck, otherwise I wouldn't be posting my question here...duh

```
<a target='_blank' href......></a> 
<a target="_blank" href......></a> 
<a href...... target='_blank'></a>
```

(somebody on internet stated to try setting this at the end)

Comment: It is rather an HTML issue.

Comment: What did you try? Did you use `target='_blank'` inside that `a` tag? You should post relevant code on this page instead of posting a link only.

Comment: I don't get stackoverflow, everybody is so grumpy here. Always complaining that code is not relevant.
You ask a question that I already answered in my question?
Is it so hard to be friendly here and to read my problem. If I was a coder like you guys, i wouldn't have a problem? right?

Comment: The a tags contain `onclick="window.open(this.href); return false;"` so you will never be able to add `target="_blank"` and have it work. You either need to code it yourself (without the javascript) or duplicate the plugin and rewrite the a tag.It's worth noting that `_blank` is considered bad user experience because it forces a new window on the user. It if was supposed to open in a new window this would be the default behaviour. I'm not saying you shouldn't but maybe think about whether it is better for you or the user. If it is the former it's probably the wrong decision.

Comment: Hi Chris thx, do you mean that it's better to leave it as is so the links open in the same window?
The onclick and a href in one line was a trial, so don't look at that. As I edited my post I tried almost evrything also combinations. ;-)

Answer (score 0):

Use `target='_blank'` if you can edit the html

Otherwise, try changing the theme setting or try to find a new theme

ex:

```
<a href='http://www.twitter.com/' target='_blank'> open Twitter </a>
```